# How to scale the viewport to a minimum width

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, viewport

**Problem:** I have a page that looks terrible <480px and doesn't display enough relevant information to the user.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- (ex. 320px screen) set the initial scale to 1.5, but then I need to set the scale accordingly for all the screen sizes between 320-480px.
- (ex. 320px screen) set the width of your viewport to 480px, however this makes you need to scroll around the screen instead of zooming out like setting the scale would do.

**Question:** What it seems I need is a combination of the two solutions. One that will scale my viewport, but only until it shows a min-width such as 480px worth of content on the screen. Is this possible without javascript or is solution #1 what I would need to do?

**Other considerations:** Solution needs to work on all browsers/mobile (IE11+)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do but if I understand correctly, you can set this in css. Setting the width to 100% will keep it flexible to your viewport window & setting a minimum width will not allow it it get any smaller than that.

```
html,body { 
     width: 100%; 
     min-width: 480px;
     height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use media queries ?

**For example:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```